# Infinite loop waiting for thread to become alive { while !thread.isAlive ; }

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating an application, that is required to do some work in a new thread and save results to static list, then thread dies naturally. There can be only one instance of this additional thread executing at time, so when function responsible for creating thread find thread already working, it should return.

When creating my appliaction i was using this guide on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

This guide says:

```
// Create the thread object. This does not start the thread.
Worker workerObject = new Worker();
Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);

// Start the worker thread.
workerThread.Start();
Console.WriteLine("main thread: Starting worker thread...");

// Loop until worker thread activates.
while (!workerThread.IsAlive);

// Put the main thread to sleep for 1 millisecond to
// allow the worker thread to do some work:
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

So i used this code in my app:

```
if (TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread != null && TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread.IsAlive)
    return false;

TibiaControl.PathFinder Finder = new TibiaControl.PathFinder(targetX, targetY);
TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Finder.FindPath));
TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread.Start();
SystemControl.DebugMessage(0, "_findPath -- 1");
while (!TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread.IsAlive) ;
Thread.Sleep(1);
SystemControl.DebugMessage(0, "_findPath -- 2");
```

But when executing this function with high frequency (like once every 20-30ms) it happens that my app gets stuck on

```
while (!TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread.IsAlive) ;
```

line and main thread gets stuck in an infinite loop (as if thread already have it's work done before an while loop occurs). How can I fix that?

Comment: Writing code in your title doesn't make your question better. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Why do you want the main loop to pause until the worker thread starts?

Comment: If you're just going to block the main thread until the worker thread finishes what have you gained by using a worker thread?  Why not just do the work in the current thread?

Comment: Looks like you have a race condition somewhere.  You should add some form of `Mutual Exclusion` (e.g. a flag) around the thread specific code to ensure that only one thread is executing in it at a given time. EDIT: After looking at the code it seems more like the thread is not getting killed naturally; adding the Mutual Exclusion flag and setting it to `false` after the thread has completed it's job should still resolve it, although you need to look further into why the threads sometimes aren't naturally dying as there could be a memory leak somewhere

Comment: The problem was that i was waiting for thread to start. Adding a volatile bool instead of thread.IsAlive and removing while loop fixed (as testing for now) the problem.

Comment: FWIW windows doesn't care about less than 16 milliseconds, it's windows minimum time slice. if you're working on mono though, I would suggest 5 which is equal to kernel default slice of 1/200 seconds. if using a recent linux kernel this doesn't matter.

Comment: and Sleep(0) is more efficient since it has a special code-path in kernel which just reschedules your thread at the back of the queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have blindly copied some code from the example that you don't need:

```
while (!TibiaControl.PathFinder.PathFinderThread.IsAlive) ;
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

The reason they did this was to demonstrate the usefulness of their RequestStop method.

Comment: The problem was that i was waiting for thread to start. Adding a volatile bool instead of thread.IsAlive and removing while loop fixed (as testing for now) the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use that code as the source for any useful application.  First of all, there's much better ways for threads to wait.  For example, `ManualResetEventSlim`.  Second, it's hard to tell from the code you've posted whether `IsAlive` is `volatile`.  Even, then, in an x86 system that really doesn't do anything w.r.t. special code.  I would recommend using a safer and more explicit form of thread safe value reading.  For example:

```
while (0 == Interlocked.Read(ref workerThread.IsAlive));
```

Which means <strike>changing</strike> creating a new variable IsAlive <strike>to</strike> as a long.  But then, in a single CPU system you've just made the one and only CPU busy with little chance of other threads getting a chance to use it.  You should yield control to other threads:

```
while (0 == Interlocked.Read(ref workerThread.IsAlive)) Thread.Sleep(1);
```

But, I think starting with *that* sample code is a bad idea.  Try to figure out what *you* need to do and detail that...

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx

Comment: The problem was that i was waiting for thread to start. Adding a volatile bool instead of thread.IsAlive and removing while loop fixed (as testing for now) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the IsAlive loop with querying the ThreadState:

```
while (!myThread.IsAlive 
    && myThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped
    && myThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted)
{}
```

This avoids endless loops for the case the thread stops immediately after starting